# Extending my root partition on windows/ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, partitioning

[image: This is my gparted image]

I want to resize `/dev/sda5` to take all of the unallocated space (242.25 GiB). How can I accomplish this?

EDIT 1:

```
swapon output:
NAME         TYPE       SIZE USED  PRIO
/dev/sda6    partition  14G  0B        -1

sudo blkid | grep swap output
/dev/sda6: UUID="d4ae2fb5-2069-4b6d-b86d-e8c94ebf0fd9

grep swap /etc/fstab output:
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during reparation
UUID=d4ae2fb5-2069-4b6d-b86d-e8c94ebf0fd9 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: No way to do it without moving /dev/sda5 and the extended partition. I'd say it's easier to backup and reinstall.

Comment: Is there a way to move it? I really don't fell like reinstalling it right now.

Comment: Yes, of course there is. Use the search function of the site.

Comment: Before I give you detailed instructions, I need to know why I don't see a swap partition? How much RAM do you have? Is your computer a newer UEFI machine, or an older BIOS machine?

Comment: ps: do you have any important files on sda5? Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD with the same version of Ubuntu as you have installed now? Start all comments that are to my attention with `@heynnema`.

Comment: @heynnema I don't have a swap partition because I disabled the option when installing ubuntu. I have 12 GiB of RAM. My computer is an older BIOS machine. And yes I do have an ubuntu live dvd.

Comment: @Markovlaić you really should have a swap partition, or a swapfile, even with 12G RAM. And to prove it to yourself, load up LibreOffice with a few documents, and Virtualbox with a few open VM's, etc and watch what happens to your system... it'll crash, hang, or just become **very** sluggish. I'll go and complete my answer below.

Comment: @heynnema that you soo much, please save me!

Comment: @heynnema that was an autocorrect :D you saved me

Comment: @heynnema I dont have enough reputation yet since I opened my account few days ago, but I will sure remember to rate your answer when I gain some.

Comment: @Markovlaić did all the instructions work ok? Can you post a new updated gparted screenshot for me to see?

Comment: @heynnema actually my computer now doesn't load graphics when I boot to ubuntu. Everything worked fine until I changed the fstab file. When the system rebooted I got a black screen with a terminal asking to log in. After I log in I am only able to use terminal. I also can't boot from live DVD for some unknown reason. Please help!

Comment: Log into the terminal and type `swapon` and `sudo blkid | grep swap` and `grep swap /etc/fstab` and tell me what the output is by editing your reply into your original question. Visually make sure that the UUID's in the 2nd and 3rd commands matches exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51832/discussion-between-marko-vlaic-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning: FIRST backup all important files on /dev/sda5**

To perform the required tasks, you'll need to have a Ubuntu Live DVD for the same version of Ubuntu that you have installed now.

Before (unallocated and sda4/sda5)

[image]

After (sda4/sda5 and swap)

[image]

## In gparted:

- boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD in `Try Ubuntu` mode
- start `gparted` from the Unity dashboard
- make sure that you're viewing the proper hard disk... if you only have one hard disk, it's probably /dev/sda
- make sure it's set to align partitions on MiB boundries
- note: the following steps may vary slightly and you should stay in contact if there are any difficulties or questions.
- info: partitions are **moved** or **resized** in two different ways. The easy way is to use the graphic representation and use the hand cursor to drag/**move** partitions, and grab handles on the left/right sides of partitions to **resize**. The other way is to enter specific numeric values into the **space before** and **space after** entry fields. We'll use both methods here.
- in the lower pane of gparted, right-click on sda4 and select **move**/resize
- in the new window that appears, enter a 1 (one) into the **space before** and the **space after** numeric fields, then click OK
- observe the graphic representation in the upper pane, and confirm that sda4 covers the previous unallocated space, and its original location, and that sda5 still only takes up a small portion of the **left** side sda4
- **if it doesn't appear as instructed, then STOP**
- if it does appear as instructed, click the **Apply** icon
- right-click on sda5 and select move/**resize**
- in the graphic representation, drag the right side of sda5 to the right, leaving 12-16G free space at the right, then click OK
- in the bottom pane, right-click on the 12-16G of unallocated space that appears to the right of sda5, and select **new** **logical** partition, with a **swap** file system, sized to consume the entire 12-16G space, then click OK
- compare the upper pane with the "After" image that I posted earlier, and **if they don't look similar** *(the yellow portion represents swap)*, then **STOP**, if they do look similar click the **Apply** icon
- note the sda representation of the new swap partition, it'll probably be **sda6**, you'll need that later when you edit /etc/fstab

## In Ubuntu:

- boot into Ubuntu

In `terminal`...

- edit: type `sudo mkswap /dev/sda6` changing sda6 to the sdaX number from the previous step, if required
- type `sudo blkid` and note the **UUID** of the new swap partition, and copy it to the clipboard
- type `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak` # to backup fstab
- type `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab` # to edit fstab
- add the following two lines to the end of fstab, changing the **UUID** to the one noted above, by pasting the clipboard

```
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during repartition
UUID=071f8b0e-8e16-4f4d-90ff-a4ae9cc56e2b  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

- check your work, save the file, and quit gedit
- type `sudo swapon -a` # to enable swap
- type `swapon` and verify that it shows memory and swap
- type `reboot`

## In Windows:

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- click on `change what the power buttons do`
- click on `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast start`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off` *(turns off hibernation)*
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve that chkdsk runs at next boot time
- reboot Windows